# smash: command not found (npm)

Tags: d3.js, npm, elm

I am trying to install an [Elm-d3](https://github.com/seliopou/elm-d3) connector I found on Github.

- [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) is a functional-reactive programming language Evan Czaplicki
- [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) is the popular graphics meta-library by Michael Bostock

> **Elm-d3** enables you create type-safe, composable widgets using HTML, SVG, and CSS. D3 acts as a conceptual basis for the library, as well as an alternative renderer for Elm.

---

The first two install instructions are:

```
npm install smash
make
```

Installing smash goes smoothly (although I have to use `sudo`)

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/smash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/smash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/queue-async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/queue-async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
smash@0.0.12 ../../../node_modules/smash
├── queue-async@1.0.7
└── optimist@0.3.7 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
```

However after installing I can't seem to refer to [smash](https://github.com/mbostock/smash), which merges Javascript files together into one.

```
$ smash
bash: smash: command not found
```

---

I don't think `node.js` is actually used anywhere, just organized by `npm`.  **Why can't I find smash after installing it?**

When I try to run `make` I get related errors:

```
make: node_modules/.bin/smash: Command not found
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: Can you confirm two things: that there is a symlink in `node_modules/.bin/smash`; and if it exists that the file that the symlink points to is executable by your user?

Comment: @seliopou doing `npm -g install smash` I can find smash but make says `make: node_modules/.bin/smash: Command not found` and also `elm --src-dir=src --make -o src/D3.elm`.  I am reading the Makefile it says a bunch of interesting things

Comment: @seliopou I switched `node_modules/.bin/smash` to say just `smash` in the makefile and it ran.  moving forward :)

Comment: I think I know what happened to you before. If you `npm install ...` a module, and you don't have either A. a `node_modules` folder OR B. a `package.json` file in that directory, npm looks up your directory tree starting at the current directory and installs it in the first location that satisfies A or B. Try using `npm init` to create a package.json file, and then try the `npm install smash` `make` and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use smash (or just about any other npm program) from your bash prompt you need to install it globally by using the `-g` flag.

```
npm install -g smash
```